# How to run a shell command from a Meson script?

Tags: shell, command, file-copying, meson-build

How can I run a shell command (e.g. `cp`, i.e. copy) from a Meson build script?

I tried with this code:

```
r = run_command('cp', 'test.txt', 'test2.txt')

if r.returncode() != 0
  warning('Command failed')
endif
```

But it does nothing.
`run_command` runs successfully (0 is returned), but not file is copied.
If I substitute `cp` with `cp3`, I get an error message from Meson, the process terminates and it does not even get to the following line.
If I substitute `test.txt` with `test0.txt`, I get an error message from the script.

So the script behaves correctly, but the command leaves no trace of itself on the file system.

Is `run_command` the only way to run a shell command from Meson? What am I doing wrong?

---

Reference:  https://mesonbuild.com/External-commands.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command is run from [unspecified](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#run_command) directory, so, try specifying full file names, e.g.:

```
source = join_paths(meson.source_root(), 'test.txt')
dest = join_paths(meson.build_root(), 'test2.txt')
message('copying @0@ to @1@ ...'.format(source, dest))
r = run_command('cp', source, dest)
```

Comment: It works. A note: `join_paths` does not seem to work as an append. E.g.: `join_path('/path/to/', 'subdir/test.txt') --> /path/to/subdir/test.txt`, while `join_path('/path/to/', '/subdir/test.txt') --> /subdir/test.txt`

Comment: @Pietro exactly, that's why ref manual says for join_paths: "If any one of the individual segments is an absolute path, all segments before it are dropped."

Answer (score 1):

I came across this answer recently.

First, in recent meson releases `source_root` and `build_root` are deprecated. Use `current_source_dir` and `current_build_dir` functions instead.

Second, `run_command` is always run even for the `clean` operation, better to use `custom_target` to achieve the same results if possible.